# Having Issues Compiling React App which was dumped on my plate

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I git the code..made some minor changes to a few componenets....correcting typos
Here is the issue that when I run npm start I'm receive

> ERROR in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js Module not found:
> Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in
> /Users/xx/Desktop/REPOS/MIT_WEBS/tripsharing/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib
> @ ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 15:12-36
>
> ERROR in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js Module not found:
> Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in
> /Users/xx/Desktop/REPOS/MIT_WEBS/tripsharing/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib
> @ ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 16:9-22

```
    {
  "name": "ZZ",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "ZZ website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:wonyoungso/tripsharing.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Wonyoung So",
  "dependencies": {
    "csv": "1.1.0",
    "d3": "^4.5.0",
    "gsap": "^1.18.5",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "lodash": "4.12.0",
    "rc-slider": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-motion": "^0.4.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-retina-image": "^2.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "stats-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "textures": "^1.0.5",
    "turf": "3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: try putting `"browser":{
"child_process": false
} ` in your package.json

Comment: Same error.....